# Transformers.js in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm building a component in React and I want to use a model from huggingface. I found the package @xenova/transformers that allows to use of these models in JavaScript, but when I try to create my **pipeline instance** like this:

```
class MyExtractorPipeline {
    static task = "feature-extraction";
    static model = "Xenova/all-MiniLM-L6-v2";
    static instance = null;

    static async getInstance(model, progress_callback = null) {
        if (this.instance === null) {
            try {
                this.instance = await pipeline(this.task, model, { progress_callback }); //<= THIS IS FAILING
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(error)
            }
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
}
```

**I get this error:**

worker.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
at MyExtractorPipeline.getInstance (worker.js:17:1)
at async worker.js:77:1

**I'm sure it comes from the 'throw new Error(error)' that you can see above,** but I don't know how to solve it, I need HELP.

I tried to do console.log() of almost all the variables, and I tried to use other hugginface models...
Anything has been useful.

Comment: Never done ML in JS before, so I don't know what's wrong / how to fix it. Nevertheless, the worker seems to be requesting a JSON file but receiving a HTML document. I'd look into the network tab in your browser's devtools and see, what's being requested. Probably a wrong filename/-path (`create-react-app` returns the `index.html` file for all paths that are not a file's path iirc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your intention to load the model locally? Have you used create-react-app to initiate your project?

If so (and this might not be unique to create-react-app) I've noticed that on build, if you reference a file in your 'src' folder, it does not properly find the files (causing 'index.html' to be returned).

Try putting your local models under your project's 'public' folder. Then set the environment variable like this:

```
env.localModelPath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/models/'
```

Also, apply env setting for local loading of the model:

```
env.allowRemoteModels = false;
env.allowLocalModels = true;
```

Further reference here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: Hey Alex, do you have any suggestions how to load a model from user disk in a hugging face space?
Optimally the user would be able to provide the path of the model on his disk, or drag n drop the folder path into the hugging face space.
I'm not sure how it would work because, as you pointed out in your answer, the model needs to be in the public directory.


EDIT: The user hosting the model on hugging face is not an option for me. I want to avoid forcing the user to upload the model anywhere but into the application cache of the HF Space.

Comment: Hi @saferugdev - I store the model in an AWS S3 bucket, then assign the S3 public url to env.localModelPath.

env.localModelPath = 'https://mys3.s3.amazonaws.com/'
class MyPipeline {
    static task = 'feature-extraction'
    static model = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
    static instance = null;
    static async getInstance(progress_callback = null) {
      if (this.instance === null) {
        this.instance = pipeline(this.task, this.model, {
           quantized: true,
            progress_callback
      });
    }
    return this.instance;
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

There are many reported issues on Github, but it seems that you need to specifically define that you do not want to use local models.

```
import { env } from '@xenova/transformers';

env.allowLocalModels = false;
```

If that does not work, you need to further explicitly prevent the lib from using browser cache.

```
import { env } from '@xenova/transformers';

env.allowLocalModels = false;
env.useBrowserCache = false;
```

It varies depending on the runtime, bundler and environment. Thus, for more specific error explanation, try searching for 'Unexpected token' on issues section of the lib.